# How can I break a third party iframe on my site, with code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am not a programmer.

Someone has scraped my site home page source code and placed their iframe over it, so that when the page is fetched it displays their content.

The iframe is not immediately apparent but it's there, just well hidden. These sites are all hosted on hacked servers running WordPress. They still display our site links and architecture that is being delivered by our server. There are currently over 160 such sites built using the same method.

I believe that they have disabled js so that may not be an option.

I know that we can break out of an iframe if it's our site in the frame.

Is there any way, either on the server side or on the page to break their iframe and force our page to the top?

If we can break it, then our code becomes worthless and with a bit of luck they may stop using it.

Update:

Just wanted to add a few points to anyone who has any ideas.

1, They already have the code, only things being served are the images and CSS files because they have only left those links in the page.

2, They are showing their site by floating it with a z-index on top of everything, which is why when you view src you see the site above and not the site that is floated in the iframe.

3, The iframe is visible if you inspect element with firefox and scroll to the top of the page you can see the iframe they are using.

Comment: Check who is calling your page, before serving it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based upon the additions (currently in an answer), since they have your code there's not much you can do about breaking out of the iframe.

Depending upon your server environment you could try determining what page is requesting your images and CSS, and then display modified versions to those accessing the scraped versions. The key word for your searches is 'hotlinking.'

Possible modifications could include not serving the assets (images/CSS), or returning a CSS file that just does a `display:none;` on HTML elements to hide.

It might be a fool's errand, but trying to contact the hosts of the hacked servers might be a good idea, but I can't honestly say that it will get you very far, and might be a waste of time for the majority of them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer James.

Comment: Just a follow-up for James. Your suggestion about returning a css file that does a display:none works perfectly. The hacked sites now show a blank page. Hopefully they will stop using our source code and move to something easier. Thanks for your help.